# How do I style HtmlView, such as center text?

Tags: nativescript

I'm using a HtmlView for some html text I get through a json feed. However, I want to center it under an image and am having trouble figuring out how to style the elements inside the view. I know how to set the width of the element itself, but how do I style the content?

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align` with style attribute,

```
<HtmlView html="<div style='text-align: center'>this text should be in center of view</div>"></HtmlView>
```

**Note:** I was told that `text-align: center` may not work in Android < v7.0. In which case you will have to set the gravity on native view.

```
// Do this in loaded event of TextView
const nativeView = args.object.android;
if (nativeView) {
    nativeView.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=o9ka1V) is a Playground sample.